# Bijective and continuous $\implies $ monotone.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that a bijective continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is monotone ?

**My attempts**

Let $a<b$. Since $f$ is injective, $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Therefore $f(a)<f(b)$ or $f(a)>f(b)$. Suppose with out loss of generality that $f(a)<f(b)$ and let $x,y\in[a,b]$ such that $x<y$. By injectivity, $f(x)\notin \{f(a),f(b)\}$. Suppose that $f(x)\notin ]f(a),f(b)[$.

If $f(x)<f(a)$, by the intermediate value theorem (IVT), there is a $c\in[x,b]$ such that $f(x)=f(c)$ what contradict injectivity.

If $f(x)>f(b)$, by IVT we have a $d\in[a,x]$ such that $f(d)=f(b)$ what also contradict injectivity.

Then $f(x)\in [f(a),f(b)]$. We can show as well that $f(y)\in [f(a),f(b)]$ and that $f(x)<f(y)$. Therefore we have that $f(x)<f(y)$ if $x<y$.

The problem is that I'm not sure that my proof is finish. I just proved that for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$, s.t. $a<b$ the function $f$ is monotone on $[a,b]$. But may be it's enough to say that it's monotone on all $\mathbb R$. What do you think ?

Comment: Since it works for all possible pairs of values, it works on the real line.

Comment: It's not duplicate since the OP is not asking how to prove the statement on $[a,b]$ but how to generalize the result on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: For each pair $x < y$ in  $\mathbb {R}$, they are contained in a compact interval, apply your argument, (wolg) we get $f(x) < f(y)$. And we are done.

Comment: Little correction: in the 2nd paragraph of your proof, "If $f(x) < f(a)$, ... there is $c \in [x, b]$ such that..." Here you have "$f(x) = f(c)$", but you mean/want $f(a) = f(c)$, or better still, **$f(c) = f(a)$**. (In the next paragraph when considering the other endpoint, you use that order, "we have $d \in [a, x]$ such that $f(d) = f(b)$" -- it reads better, I think).

Comment: And no, I don't see that you're done -- so far you've shown that for all $a, b$,  $f$ is monotone on $[a, b]$; however, it may be monotone increasing on $[0, 1]$ but decreasing on $[100, 101]$. So, next show that (\*) for any $b' > b$, $f$ is increasing on $[a, b']$, and similarly that (\*\*) for any $a' < a$, $f$ is increasing on $[a', b]$.  Having shown (\*), you can hand-wave through (\*\*) "by symmetry". *Then* you're done.